# Converting String to HTML - string to "a href" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I am having some trouble getting some HTML links to add to my HTML page. I have tried searching around but nothing has helped thus far.

My page will initially load a snippet:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; color: rgb(0, 255, 144)">Roster: </div>
<span id="teamRoster"></span>
<br />
```

Which appears like `Roster:` in the View

Right now my snippet has been modified to add names:

```
var rosterListings = "";
for (var i = 0; i < teamRoster.length; i++) {
    rosterListings = rosterListings + teamRoster[i] + ", ";
}
$("#teamRoster").text(rosterListings);
```

Which will update my View to `Roster: John, Frank, Susan, etc..`

However, I am trying to now add `<a href>` tags around each person and turn them all into actual links. My attempt looks like this

```
var rosterListings = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < teamRoster.length; i++) {
        rosterListings = rosterListings + " <a href='" + idList[i] + "'>" + teamRoster[i] + "</a>,";
    }
    $("#teamRoster").text(rosterListings);
```

which displays as

`Roster: <a href='#'>John</a>, <a href='#'>Frank</a>, etc..`

I understand why this occurring since I am setting actual text/strings, but is there a way to convert this string into HTML elements? I have tried a few `$.parseHTML` code snippets that I found from Googling but I must be implementing them all wrong.

Comment: replace `$("#teamRoster").text(rosterListings);` with `$("#teamRoster").html(rosterListings);`

Comment: @Justcode you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Justcode Thank you! Had no idea it was that simple! If you add that as an answer I shall mark it!

Comment: ok i am adding it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, solution is quite obvious

Just replace

```
 $("#teamRoster").text(rosterListings);
```

With:

```
$("#teamRoster").html(rosterListings);
```

Because if you use it as a text then it will treat it as the text and if you write html then it will treat it as a html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), which will insert *only* text into the `span`, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/4B924/).

You need to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) if you want what is inserted to actually render as HTML.

So, try this:

```
$("#teamRoster").html(rosterListings);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/4B924/1/)

Also note that the way you've set up your `for` loop causes an extra comma to be placed at the end of the list; I've fixed that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/4B924/3/) by checking whether it's the last element:

```
if (i !== teamRoster.length - 1) {
        rosterListings = rosterListings + " <a href='" + idList[i] + "'>" + teamRoster[i] + "</a>,";
} else {
        rosterListings = rosterListings + " and <a href='" + idList[i] + "'>" + teamRoster[i] + "</a>.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Just code points out, you want to use the `html` method, not the `text` method.  `html()` is jQuery's wrapper for `innerHTML`, which injects the string as html.

Here is a jsFiddle showing the difference:

http://jsfiddle.net/89nxt/

```
$("#teamRosterHtml").html("<a href='#'>John</a> <a href='#'>Frank</a>");
$("#teamRosterText").text("<a href='#'>John</a> <a href='#'>Frank</a>");
```